# Saber si un determinado commit de git tiene un tag

Tags: git, jenkins

Necesito saber si es posible saber si un determinado commit de git esta taggeado en un job de jenkins.

De momento creo que lo he conseguido ejecutando el siguiente comando

```
TAG="git show-ref --tags | grep ${GIT_COMMIT}"
                    
if( ${TAG} == "" ){
    return false
}
```

Pero me gustaría saber otras opciones

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres a determinar si un tag esta apuntando a un commit especifico podría ser

```
GIT_COMMIT=1af9a8a
TAG=`git describe --tags $GIT_COMMIT`
if [[ $TAG == *"-"* ]]; then
    echo false
else
    echo true
fi
```

**git-describe** encuentra el tag mas reciente que se puede alcanzar desde el commit. Si el tag apunta al commit entonces solo se obtiene el nombre del tag, si el tag encontrado no apunta a ese commit entonces se obtiene el nombre del tag y otros datos concatenados (como el número de commits hasta el tag más cercano)

Por ejemplo, si un repositorio tuviese este log.

```
ba84a73 (HEAD -> main) commit 3
1af9a8a commit 2
0ebef13 (tag: v2) commit 1
664e0c1 (tag: v1) commit 0
```

La salida sería

```
git describe ba84a73
v2-2-gba84a73

git describe 1af9a8a
v2-1-g1af9a8a

git describe 0ebef13
v2

git describe 664e0c1
v1
```